# python mail-parser comandline tool is not running on crontab

Tags: python, linux, shell, email, cron

I want to run the python comandline tool in a shell script. that works in a user context fine but in a crontab context the script mailparser ist not working.

thats my PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash

my crontab looks like

- - - - - /home/komando/get.sh

my shell script get
starts with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and the mailparse comand
mailparser -f $x -b > $DIR/process/extract/$i/filteredmessage.html

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mail-parser

the tool is located in /usr/local/bin/mailparser

and looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'mail-parser==1.2.0','console_scripts','mailparser'
__requires__ = 'mail-parser==1.2.0'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('mail-parser==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'mailparser')()
    )
```

Comment: can you basically run your script manually without crontab ?

Comment: Yes its running without error.

Comment: Maybe /usr/local/bin is not in the cron path?